# Self join query in linq

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have `Employee` list

```
EmpId EmpName ManagerId Salary
```

`ManagerId` is one of the `EmpId`

I want to get `EmpName`,`ManagerName`(using `ManagerId` to get `EmpName`) from the same list.
please any one help me..

```
List<Employee> emp = new List<Employee>();
emp.Add(new Employee() { Empid = 1, EmpName = "Arivu", Managerid=null, salary = 20000 });
emp.Add(new Employee() { Empid = 2, EmpName = "kavi", Managerid=1, salary = 30000 });
emp.Add(new Employee() { Empid = 6, EmpName = "karthi", Managerid = 1, salary = 307000 });
emp.Add(new Employee() { Empid = 3, EmpName = "Anbu", Managerid = 2, salary = 40000 });
emp.Add(new Employee() { Empid = 4, EmpName = "asfdsf", Managerid = 1, salary = 55000 });
emp.Add(new Employee() { Empid = 5, EmpName = "Nithya", Managerid = 3, salary = 12000 });
```

This is the list and I want to get the `empname` and `managername` from `emp` list

Comment: Provide some code, can you?

Comment: Sample code please....

Comment: If no code is given then read this first: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/LINQ-Join-Operators-dabef4e9

Answer (score 6):

```
var result = from emp in empList 
             join mng in empList on emp.ManagerId equals mng.Id
             select new { 
                           emp.EmpName,
                           ManagerName =  mng.EmpName 
                         };
```

or

```
var result = empList.Join(empList , emp => emp.ManagerId, mng => mng.EmpId, (emp, mng) => new
            {
                emp.EmpName,
                ManagerName = mng.EmpName
            });
```

Comment: you only used object but my problem the object is inside the list

Comment: this works for list, see update (just changed the names)

Answer (score 0):

I quite often try to avoid a `SelectMany` query as they aren't always the most readable. So depending on the circumstance I might do something like this:

```
var map = emp.ToDictionary(e => (int?)e.Empid);

Func<int?, string> getNameFromId = i =>
    i == null ? "n/a" : map[i].EmpName;

var query =
    from e in emp
    select new
    {
        e.EmpName,
        ManagerName = getNameFromId(e.Managerid)
    };
```

I find this kind of thing a little more explicit, especially because it explicitly handles the case when someone doesn't have a manager.